# Does anyone know of a script that can convert a wav to a Grub beep script?

Tags: grub2, scripts, conversion, wav

Does anyone know where a script would be that can convert a wav file into a Grub beep code? It'd be a great help! Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on the complexity of the audio. Normally humans have to do the conversion since in essence you're doing the mathematical equivalent of an anti-derivative and that assumes the input signal is a single instrument.

Its similar to asking if you can convert a rasterized image into a vector graphic.

Comment: +1 for hilarious. Related (with some tunes): https://askubuntu.com/questions/76309/play-a-sound-before-or-after-grub-loads – It should be possible at least for `midi` IMO, let me try some things and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, my attempts got me nowhere – `wav` and `midi` are both *much* more complicated than I thought. I fear there's no easy way to achieve your goal, especially because there can be only one beep at a time.